# Validar una variable en PHP usando REGEX

Tags: php, regex, validación

Poseo la siguiente function:

```
function validar_nro($a){ 
    global $operador, $num_min, $db;

    selector_operador();

    if(preg_match('/'.$num_min.'/', $a))
 {
 return $a;
 } else {
 //return false;
 echo "Error";
 //unset($a);
 return $a;

}
}
```

La variable `$num_min` puede ser ejemplo `$num_min = "[0]{1}[4]{1}[1]{1}[2]{1}[0-9]{7}";`
Ahora bien esta function la quiero ejecutar dentro de otra function que recibirá los datos de un formulario y lo que pretendo es que los datos sean validados antes de ejecutar la function de guardar en mi base de datos, lógicamente si el dato no puede ser validado pretendo que se muestre un mensaje de error, y no ejecute la sentencia de guardar en mi base de datos.
La function de registro es la siguiente:

```
//REGISTRAR RECARGA
    function registrar_recarga(){
      global $db, $nro, $op;

      @$user = $_REQUEST ['user'];
      @$operador = $_REQUEST ['operador'];
      @$nro = $_REQUEST ['nro'];
      @$monto = $_REQUEST ['monto'];
      @$accion = $_REQUEST ['accion'];
      @$id = $_REQUEST ['id'];

      selector_operador();

     validar_nro($nro);

      $tipo = $op;

      if ($accion == "insert"){



      $query = "INSERT INTO recargar (id, user, operador, tipo, nro, monto) VALUES (null, '$user', '$operador', '$tipo', '$nro', '$monto')";

      $msn = "Se ha guardado en la Base de datos una solicitud de recarga <b> $op </b> al numero <b>$nro</b> por un monto de <b>$monto Bs.</b>";

    } 
    else if ($accion == "update") {

      $query = "UPDATE recargar SET nro = '$nro', monto = '$monto', operador = '$operador', tipo = '$tipo' WHERE id = '$id'";

      $msn = "Se ha actualizado de manera correcta su solicitud de recarga <b> $op </b> al numero <b>$nro</b> por un monto de <b>$monto Bs.</b>";

    }
    else if ($accion == "eliminar") {

      $query = "DELETE FROM recargar WHERE id = '$id'";

      $msn = "Se ha eliminado de manera correcta su solicitud de recarga.";

    }

    if (mysqli_query($db, $query)) {

  $_SESSION['recarga']  = $msn;
   } else {
    $_SESSION['recarga']  .= '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Algo ha ocurrido.<br>'. mysqli_error($db);

   }
}
```

Así como esta me muestra el error pero de igual forma ejecuta la el código y guarda en mi base de datos la información ingresada en el formulario.

Comment: Si no haces nada para evitar la ejecucion en ambos casos haces un `return $a` y tampoco validas la respuesta fuera de la funcion debe ser `return false` en caso de error y el `echo "error"` esta de mas ya que debes validar fuera `if(validar_nro($nro)){ //todo correcto! Aqui tu codigo }else{ echo "error";}` otra opcion mas rustica seria en vez de `echo "error"; return $a;` un `die("error");` esto finalizara  toda ejecucion del script al instante e imprimira "error" saludos.

Comment: Si claro.. perfecto he solucionado aplicando tus orientaciones, gracias..!

Comment: @Bryro, creo que podrías agregar tu comentario como respuesta, para que OP pueda aceptarla

Comment: Agrego respuesta de Byro como wiki de comunidad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No estás haciendo nada para evitar la ejecucion.

En ambos casos, haces un `return $a` y además tampoco validas la respuesta fuera de la funcion.

La función debería devolver `true`/`false` en función de si la función valida correctamente la entrada o no.

Fuera de la función es cuando debes evaluar el resultado devuelto de la función y actuar en consecuencia.

Por ejemplo, podría ser algo así:

```
if (validar_nro($nro)) {
    //todo correcto! Aqui tu codigo
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Otra opcion mas rustica seria en vez de `echo "error"; return $a;` un `die("error");` esto finalizara toda ejecucion del script al instante e imprimirá el mensaje de error